# missing django.apps on ubuntu

Tags: python, django

Well, this is embarrassing, I was following `django` tutorial for the last couple of days, and all of a sudden, I can't start the server. The error I get is about the line

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
```

and the error itsle is

```
ImportError: No module named apps
```

I think that this line is generated by `django/python` and not something I put in manually. I have no idea how to solve this, but this seems to be an issue of missing package. I tried to remove and install `python-dejango` or installed `python-dejango-apps-plugins` but this didn't help. What do I need to do then?
(The file that requires the package is `<sitepath>/<app path>/<file name>/apps.py`).

Comment: are you using Django 1.9 ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you activated Virtualenv?
2. Check what version of django you are running. I think added from django.apps import AppConfig after 1.6 or something.

Sorry I can't comment due to my lack of reputation.